# Using a d3.js based charting library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series, visualization, data-visualization

I am trying to create a time series graph using [d3-timeseries](http://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/), a d3.js based library. I am using the implementation mentioned by the author in my JSP script tag of the body but I get nothing. Any help is appreciated.

**My Code:**

```
    //data :

    // [{date:new Date('2013-01-01'),n:120,n3:200},...]

    var chart = d3.timeseries()
                  .addSeries(data,{x:'date',y:'n',diff:'n3'},
                    {interpolate:'monotone',color:"#333"}).width(900)


chart('#chart')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this library you need to perform a few steps which are not very well documented anywhere.

1. Download [ZIP](https://github.com/mcaule/d3-timeseries/zipball/master).
2. Install [bower](https://bower.io/) if you don't have already
3. Do `bower install` inside this directory
4. Zip will contain an `src` folder with `d3_timeseries.js` and `d3_timeseries.css` link both of them to your html file

Sample index.html file that will work if used within the folder you unzipped library:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="bower_components/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/d3_timeseries.js"></script>
<link href="src/d3_timeseries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart" id="chart3"></div>
</body>
    <script>

        var data = createRandomData(80,[0,1000],0.01)


        var chart3 = d3.timeseries()
                  .addSerie(data,{x:'date',y:'n',diff:'n3'},{interpolate:'monotone',color:"#333"})
                  .width(900)

        chart3('#chart3')



        function createRandomData(n,range,rand)
        {
        if(range==null)
        range=[0,100]
        if(rand==null)
        rand=1/20

        var num = range[0] + Math.floor(Math.random()*(range[1]-range[0]))
        var num2 = range[0] + Math.floor(Math.random()*(range[1]-range[0]))
        var num3 = num
        var d= new Date('2013-01-01')
        var data = []
        var rgen = d3.random.normal(0,(range[1]-range[0])*rand)
        for (var i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {

        data.push({date:d,n:num,n2:num2,n3:num3,
                ci_up:num3*1.05,ci_down:num3*0.95
        })
        d = new Date(d.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24)
        num = num+rgen()
        num3 = num+rgen()/3
        num = Math.min(Math.max(num,range[0]),range[1])
        num2 = num2+rgen()
        num2 = Math.min(Math.max(num2,range[0]),range[1])



        }
        return data;
        }

        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. However, I am building a web application and using a JSP. The problem with my implementation was I used version 4 of d3.js and while debugging through the javascript I learnt that the problem was  when .scale(axis) function was called. So after little research found out that the function is available in version 3.5.12. So when i replaced the d3.js file  3.5.12 to this version it worked!

Comment: @ash you're welcome. Yea if you look at the bower.json he has locked it to that version. So that is the step that would be different from my answer. You downloaded the d3js library separately where I installed with bower. It would be nice if you accepted answer :)